# Visual Studios won't update action of form

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

This has been really frustrating. I changed the action of my form in order to send it to a different webform for testing, but no matter what I do, it still sends it to the old webform. There is no mention of this webform anywhere in the code any longer, and if I run the initial page outside of visual studios, it directs to the correct webform, but for some reason visual studios continues to direct to the old one. Any possible ideas?

```
<form onSubmit="return validate()" method="post" name="form1" 
          action="http://localhost:65076/WebForm7.aspx">
<input type="submit" value="Calculate Risk" style="float:right">
</form>
```

This should send me to webform7.aspx, but it always sends me to webform1.aspx

EDIT: At this point, I've created a new html page, copied the contents of the one above, renamed the form to name="form2", and gotten it to direct correctly, but I'd still really like to know why I'm not being allowed to change my action.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Sure. I just wasn't really sure what to post.

Comment: And what is in `validate()`?